# How to take file path from excel in robot framework

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, pycharm, robotframework, automation-testing

I want to upload a text file in application under test.
The path of text file is put in one of the cells of excel.
I tried using excel library but I am facing issue here.
My code is not identifying excel library.
I have installed robot framework excel library package in pycharm.
Below is my excel and code snippet.

```
*** Settings ***
    Library           Selenium2Library
    Library           ExcelLibrary
    Library           Collections

*** Variables ***
${path_excel}   D:\\Users\\test.xls

*** Test Cases ***
open Excel    ${path_excel}
   #Click File Upload Here   
    Choose File   xpath=//input[@class="dz-hidden-input"]    ${path}
    

*** Keywords ***
[Arguments]  ${path}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give your test case a name and run the excel keyword within it (indented)

e.g.

```
*** Settings ***
Library           Selenium2Library
Library           ExcelLibrary
Library           Collections

*** Test Cases ***
Test Case A
   ${path}  Get Path From Excel   D:\\Users\\test.xls
   Choose File   xpath=//input[@class="dz-hidden-input"]    ${path}

*** Keywords ***
Get Path From Excel
    [Arguments]  ${excel_file_path}
    Open Excel    ${excel_file_path}
    ${path}   Read Cell Data By Name   Robot_framework   A2
    [Return]  ${path}
```

Your keyword also needs a name, just argument in keyword section isn't correct format, you use a keyword similar to how functions work in other languages

[User Keyword Syntax](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#toc-entry-299)

Comment: Thanks Matthew but it is not working. Can you elaborate more specific with my example.

Comment: @Amaze_Rock can you tell me please the error you are getting in the output?

Comment: I have put this in keywords *** Keywords ***
${my_data}
    open Excel    ${path_excel}
    :For    ${i}    in range     2

    \   ${my_data}    Read Cell Data By Name    Robot_framework    A${i}
    \   Append To List    ${my_datalist}      ${my_data}

    Log    ${my_data} and then below under test case Choose File   xpath=//input[@class="dz-hidden-input"]  ${my_data} and error is Keyword '${my_data}' expected 0 arguments, got 1.

Comment: @Amaze_Rock okay I added a basic example of how to define a keyword, although this is unrelated to the question of not identifying an excel keyword. You really need to look up some fundamentals in the docs like in the link

Comment: Another error Replacing variables from keyword return value failed: Variable '${Path}' not found.
I think it is not reading the cell where file path has been defined to upload.

Comment: @Amaze_Rock I made the line a comment so you can put in your code how you want it. I'll update the example  but I'm not sure what you want to do with the for loop

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243651/discussion-between-matthew-king-and-amaze-rock).

Comment: Its working Matthew. Actually I have done that but somewhere it was taking a space. Its Resolved. Thanks !